# MySQL join many to many single row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables that I want to combine, see below for details:

### product

- productID
- name
- price

### prod_cat

- productID
- categoryID

### category

- categoryID
- name

### joined

product.productID category.categoryID product.name product.price category.name(each one though, since a product can belong to more than one category)

What I want to do is get each product with the categories that relate to them in a single query. How would I got about this?

Comment: Your "joined" section could use clarification

Comment: @OMG Ponies Ok let me try. What I am wanting to do when I join is the have my product be listed once in a query with all the categories that this product belongs to. Is that even possible? Let me know if this is to vague.

Comment: Update the question, not respond in a comment.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
SELECT
    product.productID,
    category.categoryID,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    category.name
FROM product
JOIN product_cat ON product.productID = product_cat.productID
JOIN category ON category.categoryID = product_cat.categoryID
```

If a product could be in no categories and you still want to return it, change JOIN to LEFT JOIN in both places.

An alternative approach:

```
SELECT
    product.productID,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(category.name)
FROM product
JOIN product_cat ON product.productID = product_cat.productID
JOIN category ON category.categoryID = product_cat.categoryID
GROUP BY product.productID
```

However it might be better just to use two queries instead of putting multiple values into a single cell.

Comment: The problem that I have is this still gives me 2 results when there is really only one. I want to get the product and all relating categories to it in a single query.

Comment: Use Select Distinct with above query

Comment: @Nathon Stanford II: You could check out my update where I give an alternative approach.

Comment: Woohoo! That seems to do the trick! The second one is what was tripping me up. @Majd I did try the SELECT DISTINCT on my other queries but it still came up with problems. Thanks @Mark Byers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_concat if using mySQL...

see this thread.

[SQL to join one table to another table multiple times? (Mapping products to categories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769475/sql-to-join-one-table-to-another-table-multiple-times-mapping-products-to-categ)

(possible duplicate)