# SQL-phpmyadmin (having problems with duplicated records)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

please , I wanted to design my database with all relations and stuff ...the problem is when I insert marks for two students in two subject I expect finding 4 rows after running the query ..I got 16 rows instead ..as explained in the pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: 16 records in the output is a result of the Cross Product between the three tables (`SELECT * FROM student, subjects, marks`). Please query each table individually `SELECT * FROM student`, `SELECT * FROM subjects` and `SELECT * FROM marks` to see the number of records in each individual table. To fetch a meaningful output from the three tables, please have a look at [MySQL `JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5158950/2298301)

Comment: It depends on how you retrieve data. Check how to do joins in order to get the data in the format you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` to get a meaningful response. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM student JOIN marks on ide_student = student_ide_student
JOIN subjects ON id_subject = subjects_id_subject
```