# How to store multiple items for one ID?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to set up a mysql database and it is a real brainf*ck for me.. This is my problem. Lets say I have a list of devices. like phone 1 , Phone 2 and so on. I give every device a ID named Device_ID. Every phone has accessories, but some of these accessories can be used by multiple phones.

Now I want to see all compatible accessories for one specific device. and store this in a database without having to type every accessory multiple times for every compatible device.

any help how to do this ?

thnx in advance

Comment: I'd suggest starting with looking up many-to-many relationships and link tables.

Comment: Familiar with the [Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model? Maybe you've encountered a `fooXref` table before?

Answer (score 1):

You create three tables, `phones`, `accessories` and `phone_accessories`. The third one is a joining table that only contains a `phone_id` and an `accessory_id`. Each accessory is given one row in the `accessories` table, and when you say that an accessory can be used for a phone, you create one row in the `phone_accessories` table that contains the ID of the phone and accessory. Then you can use MySQL joins to get all accessories for a phone or all phones for an accessory

Comment: thnx, I already created a many to many relationship. I have got 3 tables now devices , accessories and devices_accesoires. with Device_id and Accessory_id. Now I also want the price of the accessories. I assume I create another column in Accessories named Price. and then I will be able to get the accessory and price?

Comment: Yup, that's how you would do it

Comment: Great then there is only one question left. How can get this data in php from the database. I know how to get data from the database, but with a many to many structure I don't know what to select.

Comment: You just need to do two joins in the query. Take a look at this stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158950/mysql-join-many-to-many-single-row

Comment: Followed the post and got up with this code but it outputs 0 results.

Comment: I'm not convinced either of you quite get how SO is supposed to work