# mysql check multiple column in on statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in 1 `left join` query in which I want to check multiple columns in on statement.

By default in the database, some column is null which I want to check in the `on` statement.

Now the issue is when I run a query using the `OR` operator it only runs the 1st condition and the rest are skipped.

If I use `AND` operator it throws an error.

So is there any way to get data from multiple conditions?

Here is my query:

```
$data = "SELECT 
  b.book_name, b.book_id, 
  b.cats_id, b.cats_id1, 
  b.cats_id2, b.cats_id3, 
  b.cats_id4, b.cats_id5, 
  b.cats_id6, 
  b.book_rating, 
  b.book_author, 
  b.book_stock, 
  b.book_publisher, 
  b.book_front_img, 
  b.book_status, 
  p.publisher_id, 
  p.publisher_name, 
  a.author_id, 
  a.author_name, 
  cat.cats_id, 
  cat.cats_name, 
  cat.cats_status 
FROM 
 `books` AS b 
  LEFT JOIN `publisher` AS p 
    ON b.book_publisher = p.publisher_id 
  LEFT JOIN `author` AS a 
    ON b.book_author = a.author_id 
  LEFT JOIN categorys As cat 
    ON b.cats_id = cat.cats_id  
    OR b.cats_id1 = cat.cats_id  
    OR b.cats_id2 = cat.cats_id 
    OR b.cats_id3 = cat.cats_id 
    OR b.cats_id4 = cat.cats_id 
    OR b.cats_id5 = cat.cats_id 
    OR b.cats_id6 = cat.cats_id 
GROUP BY 
  b.book_name 
HAVING 
  cat.cats_name = '$search_data' 
  AND b.book_status = 1 
ORDER BY 
  $sorting 
LIMIT $offset, $page_limit"
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the result you want to achieve with that data. Also, it's much easier if you provide a minimal, reproducible example: I'm guessing most of your SQL is irrelevant to the actual issue you want help with

Comment: Looking at that `LEFT JOIN categorys` clause, I'd suggest the root of your problem is actually a denormalised table structure. Fix that and it would make your query much simpler. There should be a separate `book_categories` table, rather than multiple "category" columns in the `books` table. Learn about database normalisation, and how to implement a many-to-many relationship (such as the one between your books and categories) correctly in a database.

Comment: @ADyson I already made a category table different

Comment: Yes I know you have a category table, but that isn't what I suggested. Read my comment again, and see also the second half of O. Jones' answer below. Have you studied database normalisation yet? It's an essential topic to study before you start trying to design databases

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have more than one author displayed for your multi-author books either. You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

To troubleshoot this kind of query, disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.

It looks like each `books` row has multiple category id columns.  And it looks like you want to display information from your `categorys` table for each of them.

Use `GROUP BY b.book_id, p.publisher_id, a.author_id, cats.cats_id` to prevent MySQL's bizarro handling of GROUP BY from concealing your data.

**I must add this**: your multiple `books.cats_id` columns are not the SQLish way to handle your many-to-many relationship between books and categories. In the parlance of our trade, your `books` table is *denormalized*.

What you want is a new table called `books_categorys` with two columns, `book_id` and `cats_id`. It's called a join table. When a row is present in that table, it means a particular book is in a particular category. It's the SQLish way of handling a setup where each book can be in zero or more categorys. Here's an explanation. [MySQL join many to many single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158950/mysql-join-many-to-many-single-row)

Then you remove all the `cats_id` columns from `books`, and retrieve the categories like this.

Then you do something like this SELECT to get the categories.

```sql
SELECT books.id, books.name,
       categorys.cats_id, categorys.cats_name, categorys.cats_status 
  FROM books
  JOIN books_categorys ON books.book_id = books_categorys.book_id
  JOIN categorys ON books_categorys.cats_id = categorys.cats_id
``
```